# How long until the Tesla Roadster in space turns white?

Tags: radiation, rocket-science

The car launched into space by the Falcon Heavy rocket is painted red. But it's not in any kind of protective container so it'll be exposed to direct and unfiltered sunlight for a really long time.

Will the red paint eventually be sun-bleached to white? And about how long will that take?

Comment: Not everything bleaches to white. Mars is still red.

Comment: @Pieter Sure, but is the paint on the roadster such a non-bleaching chemical? Surely it's not painted with iron oxide.

Comment: [News](https://m.timesofindia.com/home/science/tesla-car-sent-to-mars-takes-wrong-turn-into-deep-space/amp_articleshow/62835310.cms): the car is going into deep space due to miscalculated thrust of fuel. It's going into the Asteroid belt near our planet.

Comment: Personally I'm disappointed by how few references I've seen to the iconic [corvette space-drop scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Ojne2qiC4I) from *Heavy Metal*. Especially as the people who prepared the mannequin for the Tesla were clearly working from that reference.